# Data doesn't load into c++ vector correctly

Tags: c++, file-io, vector

I am trying to load a text file and import the contents into a vector of structs.

Here are my definitions

```
typedef struct
{
    string pcName, pcUsername, pcPassword, pcMessage, pcAdvertisement; //I know that
                  //this is incorrect convention. It was originally a char*
}
ENTRY;

vector<ENTRY> entries;
fstream data;
```

Here is my display data function

```
void DisplayData()
{
    std::cout << (int)(entries.size() / 5) <<" entries" << endl; 
    for(int i = 1; i <=(int)entries.size()/5; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Entry " << i << ":" << endl
             << "Name: " << entries[i].pcName << endl
             << "Username: " << entries[i].pcUsername << endl
             << "Password: " << entries[i].pcPassword << endl
             << "Message: " << entries[i].pcMessage << endl
             << "Advertisement: " << entries[i].pcAdvertisement << endl;
    }
}
```

and here is my Load Data function

```
bool LoadData(const char* filepath)
{
    std::string lineData ;
    int linenumber = 1 ;
    data.open(filepath, ios::in);
    ENTRY entry_temp;

    if(!data.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Error loading file" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    while(getline(data, lineData))
    {
             if(linenumber==1) {entry_temp.pcName            = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==2) {entry_temp.pcUsername        = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==3) {entry_temp.pcPassword        = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==4) {entry_temp.pcMessage         = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==5) {entry_temp.pcAdvertisement   = lineData;}

        entries.push_back(entry_temp);

        if(linenumber == 5)
        {
            linenumber = 0; 
        }

        linenumber++;

    }
    data.close();

    puts("Database Loaded");
    return true;
}
```

Here is the text file I am loading:

```
Name1
Username1
Password1
Message1
Ad1
```

And here is the result of the display data function after calling load data:

```
1 entries
Entry 1:
Name: Name1
Username Username1
Password:
Message:
Advertisement:
```

As you can see, the first two load but the last three don't. When I did this with an array instead of a vector, it worked fine so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Looks correct to me. I suspect there's some little detail different between what you have posted, and your ACTUAL data and/or code - try adding some code to print that data as you read it. (I personally would use `switch` instead of `if/else` for the lineNumber, but that's neither here nor there).

Comment: I just noticed that the entries.pushback should be inside the if statement but when I did that, my program didn't load anything. It just said 0 entries:

Comment: Is this the actual code? It seems like this wouldn't give the output you've shown based on the fact that each time it reads a line, it pushes that *incomplete* entry to the entries.

Comment: You're trying to 1) read data into a structure, and 2) put the structure in a container. Why don't you try displaying the structure *before* you push it into the container? That way you can cut the problem in half and save us a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: Ah, Vite has spotted an obvious problem, yes. You should have the entries `push_back` inside the `if (linenumber == 5)` - and if you don't get that far, then you need some extra printouts to follow what's going on. This sounds very much like something you can debug with a few prints in strategic places to see what it does. (By the way, you only need one `if(lineNumber==5)` - just put the `lineNumber=0` and `push_back` into the block for that.

Comment: http://ideone.com/r5OG0y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think @code-guru has the right idea, I'd take the same idea just a little further, and make your code work a little more closely with the standard library. I'd do that by reading a data item with a stream extractor, and displaying it with stream inserter. So, the extractor would look something like this:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, ENTRY &e) { 
    getline(is, e.pcName);
    getline(is, e.pcUsername);
    getline(is, e.pcPassword);
    getline(is, e.pcMessage);
    getline(is, e.pcAdvertisement);
    return is;
}
```

..and the inserter would look something like this:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, ENTRY const &e) {
    os << e.pcName << "\n";
    os << e.pcUsername << "\n";
    os << e.pcPassword << "\n";
    os << e.pcMessage << "\n";
    os << e.pcAdvertisement << "\n";
    return os;
}
```

With those in place, loading and displaying the data becomes fairly straightforward.

Load the data:

```
std::ifstream in("yourfile.txt");

std::vector<ENTRY> data((std::istream_iterator<ENTRY>(in)),
                         std::istream_iterator<ENTRY>());
```

Display the data:

```
for (auto const & e: data)
    std::cout << e << "\n";
```

For the moment, I haven't tried to duplicate the format you were using to display the data -- presumably the modifications for that should be fairly obvious.

Comment: I absolutely agree with this kind of solution.  This is beautifully elegant.  One correction, `return os;` in the second code block should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 3):

Your `DisplayData` function is a little weird, and so is your `LoadData`.

Your `LoadData` pushes back a new copy of the current `ENTRIES` entry with every line.  Your `DisplayData` starts at 1 (which is not the beginning of any vector or array), and iterates only up to the 1/5th entry of the entire vector.

This needs a heavy rework.

First, the `size()` member of any standard container returns the number of elements that it contains, and will not take the number of fields in a contained struct into account.

For future reference, you'll want to post your question in a complete, standalone example that we can immediately compile to help.  (see http://sscce.org/)

Try this modified data, which runs correctly, and see if you can tell what is being done differently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
        string pcName, pcUsername, pcPassword, pcMessage, pcAdvertisement;
}
ENTRY;

vector<ENTRY> entries;
fstream data;

bool LoadData(const char* filepath)
{
    std::string lineData ;
    int linenumber = 1 ;
    data.open(filepath, ios::in);
    ENTRY entry_temp;

    if(!data.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Error loading file" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    while(getline(data, lineData))
    {
             if(linenumber==1) {entry_temp.pcName            = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==2) {entry_temp.pcUsername        = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==3) {entry_temp.pcPassword        = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==4) {entry_temp.pcMessage         = lineData;}
        else if(linenumber==5) {entry_temp.pcAdvertisement   = lineData;}


        if(linenumber == 5)
        {
            entries.push_back(entry_temp);
            linenumber = 0; 
        }

        linenumber++;

    }

    data.close();

    puts("Database Loaded");
    return true;
}

void DisplayData()
{
    std::cout << entries.size() <<" entries" << endl; 
    for(int i = 0; i < entries.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Entry " << i << ":" << endl
             << "Name: " << entries[i].pcName << endl
             << "Username: " << entries[i].pcUsername << endl
             << "Password: " << entries[i].pcPassword << endl
             << "Message: " << entries[i].pcMessage << endl
             << "Advertisement: " << entries[i].pcAdvertisement << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    LoadData("/tmp/testdata");
    DisplayData();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I think you moved the `entries.push_back` one step too far out - it's now only done at the very end of the file - which isn't right if there is more than one "entry" in the input file.

Comment: Additionally, the typedef is very c-like.  In C++, you can declare a struct like a class, ie. `struct Entry {...};  If you know the format of your database, the getline segments don't need to be implemented in a loop, especially as it will fail to load data correctly if it's in the wrong format regardless.  You could also do better to create LoadData and DisplayData as members of the struct rather than functions operating on a global structure.

Comment: Mats:  You're correct.  I've changed it to account for multiple entries.  It's still rather unappeasing, but it will work.

Comment: Beat me to it. I was about to post nearly the same. I got rid of the `typedef struct {} ENTRY`, as you say, just use `struct ENTRY`.

One other thing: in `DisplayData` use `size_t` as the type for `i` instead of `int` to squelch comparison between signed and unsigned types.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you read each line directly into the data field where it goes:

```
getline(data, entry_temp.pcName);
getline(data, entry_temp.pcUsername);
getline(data, entry_temp.pcPassword);
getline(data, entry_temp.pcMessage);
getline(data, entry_temp.pcAdvertisement);
entries.push_back(entry_temp);
```

This makes your intent much clearer than your current while loop. It also creates a *single* entry for all 4 input lines rather than one for each input line (with the other three blank). Now you can read several "entries" by using a while loop that checks if you have reached the end of the file.

Doing this will also make printing out the data much easier since the vector will have exactly the number of entries rather than five times as many as you expect (which also eats up a lot more memory than you need to).

Comment: @MatsPetersson Feel free to upvote to show your agreement ;-)

Comment: I also agree with this.  This is much cleaner and clearer than my own answer (I was mostly focused on a quick solution, rather than better practices).

Comment: [It's missing `entry_temp.pcName` at the beginning, but that's a minor detail]

Comment: @MatsPetersson Just fixed that ;-)

Comment: @Iowa15 Please click the check mark to accept my answer. You can also vote for all the answers which you found helpful. Good luck with your C++.